# Strange request - http://66.196.81.202/error/vote

Tags: request, http-status-code-404

Hi a friend of mine is asking about the request which can for example be found here:

http://www.geoidee.ch/geodata/geoserver-2.0.0/logs/2010_11_23.request.log

His original message:

*On a couple of hundred web sites worldwide, one of the 50 most popular "File not found" error 404 is caused by the following request:

`"GET http://66.196.81.202/error/vote  HTTP/1.0"`

It originates from a user agent that purports to be an iPhone.  The two requests that hit my servers appeared to originate near Frankfort, Germany.

The IP address in the request is part of Yahoo although I doubt that Yahoo had any intentional part.

fe1.buzz.vip.re1.yahoo.com

The HTTP request has a host header 66.196.81.202

and a X-Forwarded-For of 96.6.99.16 and my IP address

I expected to be able to do a Google search and find some kind of security bulletin on it, but I found nothing.  It could just be that my search skills are deficient.*

Thanks for any pointers to what this could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a malformed attempt to use your webserver as an [open proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_proxy#Disadvantages) and game a voting system - would treat as typical unwanted bot traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a search engine spider. The IP address is listed on the [seo-wolf blog as a spider](http://seo-wolf.com/tag/search-engine-spiders) (among thousands of others)

Comment: You mean the url that is mentioned in the GET is on SEO. But that is not the requestor, it is just an IP in the request string.